# Verifying rspec mocks before the test is over

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-mocks

It seems like the standard way to use rspec mocks in a test case is to do something like this:

```rb
class MyTest
  def setup
    super
    ::RSpec::Mocks.setup(self)
  end

  def teardown
    super
    begin
      ::RSpec::Mocks.verify
    ensure
      ::RSpec::Mocks.teardown
    end
  end

  test "something"
    foo = MyFoo.new
    expect(foo).to receive(:bar).and_return(42)
    ret = SomeClass.call_bar(foo)

    assert_equal(42, ret)
  end
end
```

That works *okay*. But if `SomeClass.call_bar` used the return of `foo.bar` as the return, and something was wrong with the code such that `foo.bar` was never called, then I only receive a failure due to the `assert_equal(42, ret)` line. I don't see any error like:

```
RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: (foo).bar
    expected: 1 time
    received: 0 times
```

If I remove the `assert_equal(42, ret)` line, then I do get the rspec expectation error. But I want to verify both things, that `foo.bar` was called *and* the final return was 42. It's more important to know that `foo.bar` wasn't called since that's the source of the reason that 42 wasn't returned.

If I'm expecting something like: `expect(foo).not_to receive(:bar)`, then I do get that expectation error right at the source of the call, not later during the teardown.

Now, I can do something like put `::RSpec::Mocks.verify` just before the call to `assert_equal`, but this doesn't feel right. I'm also not sure if I should be cleaning up the mocks at this point or not.

Is there some syntax like:

```rb
  test "something"
    foo = MyFoo.new
    ret = nil

    expect(foo).to receive(:bar).and_return(42).during do
      ret = SomeClass.call_bar(foo)
    end

    assert_equal(42, ret)
  end
```

So that the verification happens immediately after the block passed to `during`? Or maybe if you have multiple doubles, you could do something like:

```rb
    expect(dbl1).to receive(:one)
    expect(dbl2).to receive(:two)
    expect(dbl3).to receive(:three)

    verify(dbl1, dbl2, dbl3).during do
      my_code
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [rspec spies](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/spies).

> Spies are an alternate type of test double that support this
>   pattern by allowing you to expect that a message has been received after the fact, using `have_received`.

You create a partial double out of your `foo` with `allow(...).to receive`, then can assert reception of the the message:

```
test "something"
  foo = MyFoo.new
  allow(foo).to receive(:bar).and_return(42)
  ret = SomeClass.call_bar(foo)
  expect(foo).to have_received(:bar)
  assert_equal(42, ret)
end
```

Comment: This will not help, as failed assertion `expect(foo).to have_received(:bar)` will abort the test.

Comment: I'd disagree on that point; the OP indicated that knowing that the call didn't happen is the more important assertion. My test as written, if the method isn't called, will result in indicating that the object didn't receive the message. If the value returned is contingent on receiving the message, then not receiving the message always implies a failure of the second test. Aggregate failures don't do anything to help debugging the cause of failure in this case, and possibly muddy the waters.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I didn't notice the change of order of the assertions. Can you edit you answer a bit, so I can remove the downvote?

Comment: This is pretty close, `allow` the call before-and and then `expect` it after... I'll give it some time to see if any other answers come in, but this being the closest will probably be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you need is to aggregate failures
https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-8/docs/aggregating-failures

In a "normal" setup, any error aborts the test and no later assertions are checked.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in regards to how to actually verify the message call.

Comment: It's still verified in the tearndown phase, it's a solution that helps with aborting the test on the first failing assertion.

Comment: That's along the lines of what I'd need, but the `assert` is from minitest and the `expect` is from rspec, so I don't think they'd be aggregated together.

Comment: Did you try it? Aggregation means that the test is not aborted after fist fail, so there's a chance that the teardown happens.

Comment: Wouldn't I need that to be a feature of minitest though? I'd need minitest to continue running the teardown after `assert_equal(42, ret)` fails. And it would have to include the failure/errors from teardown in it's reporting.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think there's any built-in way to do it, but if you add the following class:

```
class VerifyDuring
  def initialize(test, objects)
    @test = test
    @objects = objects
  end

  def during
    yield
  ensure
    begin
      @objects.each do |object|
        RSpec::Mocks.proxy_for(object).verify
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      @test.flunk e
    end
  end
end
```

And the following method to your test class:

```rb
  def verify(*objects)
    VerifyDuring.new(self, objects)
  end
```

You can do this:

```rb
    verify(dbl1, dbl2, dbl3).during do
      my_code
    end
```